# How do you say ‘confabulation’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word ‘[confabulation](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-confabulation.html)’ occurs neither in Benson, nor in Wells, nor in Vikivortaro, nor in ReVo, nor in Sonja. So, what should its rendering be?

Comment: My advice is always to focus on expressing ideas and not translating words. Could you please edit this post to include some sample sentences in context of something that you're trying to express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original meaning of *confabulate* was simply *konversi*. However, the psychiatric term is derived from the word *fabulate* (to invent a story) and refers to the unwitting combination of true and false.

*Confabulation* is a clinically significant, acquired tendency to misremember and falsify, without intent to deceive, as a consequence of brain damage (thus distinguishing it from *delusion*, which is thought to be the product of a temporary disorder of perception and belief formation).

It is an internationalism, so my suggestion is ***konfabulacio***, a safe and recognizable coinage on the model of *konversacio, manifestacio* etc. It has already been used, and appears in some online word lists [like this one](http://denizo.opia.dk/la.trezorejo/vortaroj.kaj.terminaroj/terminaroj/medicina.terminaro.eo-ru/alphabetiquesp/k.htm) or [this one](http://vortareto.free.fr/dictionnaire/esp-fr/k.htm). However, if you prefer Esperanto roots, perhaps something like ***pseŭdigado*** (like *falsado*, but less condemnatory) would be okay.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I've up-voted and accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Confabulate" is *babili*.

If you see a difference, perhaps putting into context to show the difference.

Comment: ‘confabulation’ is a noun, and ‘babili’ is a verb, so there’s one difference. And if you follow the link provided, you will see that ‘confabulation’ refers to false memory. Hope that helps.

Comment: Odd. I looked it up in a thesaurus and at dictionary dot com and it said that confabulation was small talk and chit chat.

Comment: The term "confabulation" has a more specific meaning in cognitive science. It refers to the unconscious mistaking of imagined or reconstructed details for actual memories. As such, it's a specialized term and should probably be imported into Esperanto more or less as is, with the hope that it will soon be officialized. Maybe _konfabulacii_.

Comment: Todd - Mike has already made this clear. I have attempted to make it clear that it's impossible to give a good answer to this kind of question without knowing what he's trying to say. I've requested a clarification - see my comment on the original question. "With the hope that it will soon be officialized" seems to suggest some confusion over how Esperanto works.

Answer (score 3):

"Confabulation" is a very infrequent word in English.  Most US English speakers would be hard pressed to give a clear definition.  In Esperanto, I'm not sure there's a need for a specialized or technical term, since the phenomenon can be described, rather than named.  In context, "nekohera rakontado" or some similar phrase would be clear to specialists.  On the rare occasions that specialists would be discussing the phenomenon in Esperanto . . .

Comment: I've downvoted. Any technical term that exists in English should also exist in Esperanto.

Comment: I disagree. Esperanto is not the all-encompassing language that should include words for everything. If it is required in a scientific text, then it could just be quoted as the English word. What is the point of 'esperantising' it? It just bloats the Esperanto dictionary.

Comment: @OliverMason: Bloating refers to placing an unnecessary burden on everyday speech. The everyday speech of English speakers is not hindered any by the vast and expanding stock of scientific and technical terms in English. Ditto for French, Russian, and so on. Esperanto should follow suit.